# Reading XML dynamic data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a XML column in a table contains a collection of data. Every record may hold a different collection type like sometimes customers data and sometimes invoices data etc.

How can I read that cell & convert it to a table in order to bind it to a data grid, so the collection some times looks like that

```
<ArrayOfReceiptTransfer_Receipt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ReceiptTransfer_Receipt>
    <ReceiptTransfer_Receipt_ID>77491</ReceiptTransfer_Receipt_ID>
    <ReceiptTransferID>17839</ReceiptTransferID>
    <ReceiptID>74080</ReceiptID>
    <Amount>500.00</Amount>
  </ReceiptTransfer_Receipt>
</ArrayOfReceiptTransfer_Receipt>
```

And sometimes looks like

```
<ArrayOfInvoiceBudgetItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <InvoiceBudgetItem>
    <InvoiceID>21978</InvoiceID>
    <BudgetItemID>1473</BudgetItemID>
    <Amount>12</Amount>
  </InvoiceBudgetItem>
  <InvoiceBudgetItem>
    <InvoiceID>21978</InvoiceID>
    <BudgetItemID>1475</BudgetItemID>
    <Amount>11</Amount>
  </InvoiceBudgetItem>
</ArrayOfInvoiceBudgetItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have one root tag so this will also work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string input =
            "<ArrayOfReceiptTransfer_Receipt xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" + 
              "<ReceiptTransfer_Receipt>" +
                "<ReceiptTransfer_Receipt_ID>77491</ReceiptTransfer_Receipt_ID>" +
                "<ReceiptTransferID>17839</ReceiptTransferID>" +
                "<ReceiptID>74080</ReceiptID>" +
                "<Amount>500.00</Amount>" +
              "</ReceiptTransfer_Receipt>" +
            "</ArrayOfReceiptTransfer_Receipt>";

            string xml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>{0}", input);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds.ReadXml(reader);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string input =
            "<ArrayOfReceiptTransfer_Receipt xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" + 
              "<ReceiptTransfer_Receipt>" +
                "<ReceiptTransfer_Receipt_ID>77491</ReceiptTransfer_Receipt_ID>" +
                "<ReceiptTransferID>17839</ReceiptTransferID>" +
                "<ReceiptID>74080</ReceiptID>" +
                "<Amount>500.00</Amount>" +
              "</ReceiptTransfer_Receipt>" +
            "</ArrayOfReceiptTransfer_Receipt>";

            string xml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root>{0}</root>", input);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds.ReadXml(reader);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];

        }
    }
}
​
```